# Network bytes for process subtree in Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, download

How to calculate a common number of network bytes for process (**PID** known) and its all child processes? What is the set of WinAPI functions, which allows me to obtain whole needed information? Say, I want to know, how many bytes downloaded by `git submodule update --recursive`.

Comment: I'm not sure that Windows even stores this information; I mean, what would be the point?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I sure, that Windows provide such information, and, moreover, provide ability to catch an events of child processes creation. I see in Process Explorer's output (part of SysInternals Suite from microsoft.com) and realize, that it is possible to implement required utility.

Comment: You'll have to monitor the traffic I believe

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sure, but for specific subtree of full system process tree.

Comment: So, you can just do that right?